# Apache server redirects main domain to https

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

I have this server with multiple domains running CentOS 6.2 and Apache. This server has a SSL certificate installed and working well.

Every time I browse to the main domain, without adding `http://` it shows the `https` part.

For example:

If I type `mydomain.com`
it shows the `https` page on `private_html/index.html`
instead of `public_html/index.html`

If I type `http://mydomain.com` or `http://www.mydomain.com`
it shows the correct page at `public_html/index.html`

If I type `https://mydomain.com` or `https://www.mydomain.com`
it shows the correct page at `private_html/index.html`

the problem is just that if I omit the `http` or `https` part it always shows the `https` part. I want the inverse. I want to go to `https` when I want, not when apache wants.

What may be causing this?

This is my `httpd.conf` for this domain

```
<VirtualHost 100.101.102.103:80 >
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com mysite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/cgi-bin/

        UseCanonicalName OFF

        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
                SuexecUserGroup admin admin
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
                RMode config
                RUidGid admin admin
                RGroups apache access
        </IfModule>

        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mysite.com.bytes bytes
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mysite.com.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mysite.com.error.log
        <Directory /home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html>
                Options +Includes -Indexes
                php_admin_flag safe_mode OFF
                php_admin_flag engine ON
                php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@mysite.com'

                php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 100.101.102.103:443 >
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/server.key

        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com mysite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /home/admin/domains/mysite.com/private_html
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/cgi-bin/

        UseCanonicalName OFF

        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
                SuexecUserGroup admin admin
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
                RMode config
                RUidGid admin admin
                RGroups apache access
        </IfModule>

        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mysite.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mysite.com.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mysite.com.error.log

        <Directory /home/admin/domains/mysite.com/private_html>
                Options +Includes -Indexes

                php_admin_flag safe_mode OFF
                php_admin_flag engine ON
                php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@mysite.com'

            php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has *nothing to do with apache*.  Your http service and your https service are on different ports, and this port is specified in the TCP/IP header **by the client**.  Apache is not making an arbitrary choice, it is just doing what it is supposed to do in response to a specific request made on a specific port.

In other words, it is your net client (the browser) which is selecting https when you type directly into the location bar and omit the protocol (http, ftp, https...).  If you have a history at that site, the browser will then just pick a match from its internal list.

Although that should happen only with typing in the location bar and not with links within the site, it is probably a good idea to lay the site out *without duplicate paths* in different protocols to avoid confusion.  You can still use the same domain name, just, eg, add "secure" at the beginning of the path (`https://my.domain/secure/rest-of-path`).  If the content apache is serving is supposed to be literally the same for both https and http, use symlinks or mod_rewrite (I think that is appropriate, I'm not a big apache guy) to accomplish this so the end user and web client see those paths as different.

You *can* set up apache to redirect http requests to the https port and vice versa, but you would know if you had done so.  You would also probably be able to find evidence of such a redirect in the server logs, and you could certainly find it by looking at the transaction in wireshark.

I highly recommend using wireshark to debug and learn about HTTP transactions.  The "source" and "destination" ports are under "Transmission Control Protocol".  These are set by the sender, not the receiver.  80 is normally considered http and 443 is https.  It is possible to use non-standard ports for either one, but in that case a normal net client must be told explicitly which port to use (by adding `:NNN` to the address, eg `https://my.domain:4040/path`), and obviously the server must be configured to service those ports explicitly too.

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting the browser was doing this but I have tested it with safari, firefox and chrome and all do the same thing. The problem is that I do not have an equivalent of all pages in the protected area. I suppose I will have to transfer everything to there and create a redirection, right?

Comment: All modern browsers will do this kind of thing if you have a history at the site already.  They will only do it, however, when typing directly into the location bar if you leave the protocol out (http, https, ftp...).  It will not happen if you are following links, etc, so it will not hurt the integrity of the site.  You can't solve this serverside because there is no way to tell which requests are real and which are mistakes.  The best idea, if the site is not live yet, would be to *not have any equivalents* so no such confusion can occur; just add something to the path to differentiate them.

Comment: you are right! the problem is on the browser history. Once visited the https part once the browser will always try to get there. I erased my history to the site and it is now dropping me on the http part as expected. Thanks. Please add this comment of yours as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Okay, I tacked onto the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs including the suggestion that you not duplicate paths ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given today's hardware, the extra cost of HTTPS is minuscule; some sites even recommend configuring using *only* the HTTPS version, others will redirect to it automatically. Why do you insist in using the insecure HTTP protocol?

Comment: Using ssl/tls can be a significant performance hit on the server when there are frequent small requests as is the norm for http, I suggest you google this or benchmark it yourself if you are in doubt.  Eg http://serverfault.com/questions/43692/how-much-of-a-performance-hit-for-https-vs-http-for-apache Leaving public content "insecure" would be considered irrelevant by most people.